# Wait cursor in MVVM

Tags: .net, wpf, mvvm, cursor

Need a wait cursor for long operations.
Mouse.OverrideCursor works in the ViewModel but not really an MVVM pattern.
**I have an IsBusy property - how do I get wait cursor in the View?**

This kind of works
But I only get the wait cursor over the button
I want the wait cursor on the whole Window 
I hacked in Mouse.OverrideCursor = Cursor.Wait in the converter but it feels hacky 
Is there a better way to do this?

```
<Window x:Class="WaitCursor.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WaitCursor"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Window.Resources>
        <BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="BVC"/>
        <local:ViewModel x:Key="ViewModel"/>
        <local:BusyMouseConverter x:Key="BusyToCursorConverter"/>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Window.Cursor>
        <Binding Path="IsBusy" Converter="{StaticResource BusyToCursorConverter}"/>
    </Window.Cursor>
    <Grid DataContext="{StaticResource ViewModel}">
        <Button  Content="Search" VerticalAlignment="Top"  Command="{Binding SearchCommand}" Margin="2,0,2,2"
                 Cursor="{Binding Path=IsBusy, Converter={StaticResource BusyToCursorConverter}}"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

---

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using System.Windows.Markup;

namespace WaitCursor
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
    [ValueConversion(typeof(bool), typeof(Cursors))]
    public class BusyMouseConverter : MarkupExtension, IValueConverter
    {
        public BusyMouseConverter()
        {
        }

        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            if (value is bool)
            {
                if ((bool)value)
                {
                    Mouse.OverrideCursor = Cursors.Wait;  // this works but it feels hacky
                    return Cursors.Wait;
                }
                else
                {
                    Mouse.OverrideCursor = null;
                    return null;
                }
            }

            return null;
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            if (value is Cursors)
            {
                if (value == Cursors.Wait)
                    return true;
                else
                    return false;
            }

            return null;
        }

        public override object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
        {
            return instance;
        }

        private static BusyMouseConverter instance = new BusyMouseConverter();

    }
}
```

---

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Diagnostics;


namespace WaitCursor
{
    public class ViewModelBase : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        protected void NotifyPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }
    }

    class ViewModel : ViewModelBase
    {
        private ICommand _SearchCommand;
        public ICommand SearchCommand
        {
            get
            {
                if (_SearchCommand == null)
                {
                    _SearchCommand = new RelayCommand(param => this.Search(), null);
                }
                return _SearchCommand;
            }
        }
        private bool isBusy = false;
        public bool IsBusy
        {
            get { return isBusy; }
            set
            {
                if (isBusy == value)
                    return;
                isBusy = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("IsBusy");
                NotifyPropertyChanged("Cursor");
            }
        }
        private async void Search()
        {
            IsBusy = true;
            //UIServices.SetBusyState();
            //Mouse.OverrideCursor = Cursors.Wait;
            await Task.Delay(5000);
            Debug.WriteLine("Search");
            //Mouse.OverrideCursor = null;
            IsBusy = false;
        }
    }
    public class RelayCommand : ICommand
    {
        public RelayCommand(Action<object> execute) : this(execute, null)
        {
        }
        public RelayCommand(Action<object> execute, Predicate<object> canExecute)
        {
            if (execute == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("execute");
            _execute = execute;
            _canExecute = canExecute;
        }
        public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
        {
            return _canExecute == null ? true : _canExecute(parameter);
        }
        public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
        {
            add { CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value; }
            remove { CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value; }
        }
        public void Execute(object parameter)
        {
            _execute(parameter);
        }
        private readonly Action<object> _execute;
        private readonly Predicate<object> _canExecute;
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you working in the UI thread?  Because if you are, you won't see the cursor change.  The Style should work, otherwise.

Comment: @Will Assign Mouse.OverrideCursor in the ViewModel works

Comment: The style you've posted works fine on my side. Possibly your window contains a descendant element that has its `Cursor` property set to something else, thus overriding whatever you set on your `Window` while the mouse is hovering it. I'd try setting `Window.Cursor="Wait"` to see if it is displayed as expected.

Comment: @Grx70 I will try a fresh application

Comment: @Grx70 In the process or recreate I realized it did work if the mouse was over the button.  But I want the wait on the whole window.

Comment: In the current version of the code you put your view-model in the `Window.Resources` dictionary and only set it as data context for the `Grid` inside your `Window`, so for `Window` the binding will not work, since its `DataContext` will have its default value of `null`, so you should consider setting it as the `Window.DataContext` value instead.

Comment: Now that I look back at previous versions of your question the fact that you put your view-model as a resource might just be the cause of your problems - try moving your view-model to `<Window.DataContext><local:ViewModel /></Window.DataContext>` (and remove any resource reference to `ViewModel`). That's because a `Binding` without explicitly specified source expects the data context to be present on the target object (the `Window` in this case).

Comment: @Grx70 That worked.  If you will post as an answer I will accept.  It also works as a resource if in Window.DataContext.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with this code:

```
<Window (...)>
    <Window.Resources>
        <local:ViewModel x:Key="ViewModel"/>
        <local:BusyMouseConverter x:Key="BusyToCursorConverter"/>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Window.Cursor>
        <Binding Path="IsBusy" Converter="{StaticResource BusyToCursorConverter}"/>
    </Window.Cursor>
    <Grid DataContext="{StaticResource ViewModel}">
        <Button Cursor="{Binding Path=IsBusy, Converter={StaticResource BusyToCursorConverter}}"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

is that the `Binding` will only work for `Button`, because it has the proper `DataContext` available (inherited from `Grid`). Your `Window` however has no `DataContext` set (`null` is the default value), and your binding will not work. In order to make things work you need to move your view-model to the `Window.DataContext` (it will then be inherited by all controls nested in the window):

```
<Window (...)>
    <Window.DataContext>
        <local:ViewModel />
    </Window.DataContext>
    <Window.Resources>
        <local:BusyMouseConverter x:Key="BusyToCursorConverter"/>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Window.Cursor>
        <Binding Path="IsBusy" Converter="{StaticResource BusyToCursorConverter}"/>
    </Window.Cursor>
    <Grid>
        <Button Cursor="{Binding Path=IsBusy, Converter={StaticResource BusyToCursorConverter}}"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

I'd personally refrain from keeping your view-model as a resource since the resource instance will not be the instance set as `Window.DataContext` value, which may lead to unexpected behavior.

Comment: Found I would drop the Cursor from the button as is it part of the window

Comment: That's a good move - I was about to mention it in the answer. In case you ever decide to change the busy cursor to some other value, you only need to do it in one place...

Answer (score 2):

The correct MVVM way to do this is to use an `IValueConverter`. Your ViewModel can continue to provide the logic to indicate whether the program is busy or not, via `IsBusy`. Your ViewModel should never decide what to display - this is View's scope.

Then in your View, you bind the `Cursor` property of the UserControl or Window to `IsBusy`, using a converter.

XAML:

```
<UserControl ...... Cursor="{Binding IsBusy, Converter={StaticResource MyBusyToCursorConverter}}" ....>
```

Converter:

```
public class BusyToCursorConverter : System.Windows.Data.IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value == null || !(value is bool))
            return System.Windows.Input.Cursors.Arrow;

        var isBusy = (bool)value;

        if (isBusy)
            return System.Windows.Input.Cursors.Wait;
        else
            return System.Windows.Input.Cursors.Arrow;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

### Updated

Your binding might not be triggering, which is why your converter is not being called. This is probably because of the `DataContext` not kicking in correctly.

```
<Window.Cursor>
    <Binding Path="DataContext.IsBusy" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Self}" Converter="{StaticResource BusyToCursorConverter}"/>
</Window.Cursor>
```

Comment: What are your thoughts on deriving the converter from MarkupExtension, like in this example:
http://www.briankeating.net/post/WaitCursor-and-MVVM.

Comment: My own hack method is to make the converter a singleton class, and do `Converter={x:Static {converterNamespace:BusyToCursorConverter.Instance}}`.